# Why am I getting this error message when using isNull

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have this update trigger which works, except that it logs columns even when the new and old are the same value. (This happens because of the way EntityFramework does update statements).

```
set nocount on;
    create table #updatedCols (Id int identity(1, 1), updateCol nvarchar(200))

    --find all columns that were updated and write them to temp table
    insert into #updatedCols (updateCol)
    select
        column_name
    from
        information_schema.columns
    where   
        table_name = 'Items'   
        and convert(varbinary, reverse(columns_updated())) & power(convert(bigint, 2), ordinal_position - 1) > 0

    --temp tables are used because inserted and deleted tables are not available in dynamic SQL
    select * into #tempInserted from inserted
    select * into #tempDeleted from deleted

    declare @cnt int = 1
    declare @rowCnt int
    declare @columnName varchar(1000)
    declare @sql nvarchar(4000)

    select @rowCnt = count(*) from #updatedCols

    --execute insert statement for each updated column
    while @cnt <= @rowCnt
    begin
        select @columnName = updateCol from #updatedCols where id = @cnt

        set @sql = N'
            insert into [Events] ([RecordId], [EventTypeId], [EventDate], [ColumnName], [OriginalValue], [NewValue], [TenantId], [AppUserId], [TableName])
            select
                i.Id, 2, GetUTCDate(), ''' + @columnName + ''', d.' + @columnName + ', i.' + @columnName +', i.TenantId, i.UpdatedBy, ''Item''
            from
                #tempInserted i
                join #tempDeleted d on i.Id = d.Id

            '
        exec sp_executesql @sql
        set @cnt = @cnt + 1
    end
```

So I added updated the join to filter out where the values are the same:

```
 #tempDeleted d on i.Id = d.Id and isnull(i.' + @columnName + ', '''') <> isnull(d.' +@columnName + ', '''')
```

However, I now get the error: `SqlException: Error converting data type varchar to numeric.`

I am guessing that in some cases the old value is null (and so is converted to the empty string), and the new one is an int and so Sql Server tries to cast the varchar to an int in order to compare them and an error is thrown.

Is this correct?  If so, how do I fix?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to parameterize the variable then do below

```
isnull(i.' + convert(varchar(100),@columnName) + ', '''')
```

otherwise use Parameter Definition option

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: I don't know what you mean by 'Use Parameter Definition'. Can you give me an example?

Comment: please see link above